# (Solved) 32768 row limit on writing CSV file from Serial port in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, serial-port

I am reading from a force sensor from an Arduino and through Serial port. For a research reason, I need to obtain the values of the sensor (almost) as much as possible and save it to a CSV file in each sampling point (I cannot store the data as a variable and only write it once to the CSV file). Throughout the code, I also need to read from the CSV file.

The problem I have right now is that the code (showed below) starts working normally and pretends that it is working forever normally (never throws any error). However, the CSV does not update after it reaches 32768 lines every time I run the code. I know there is a 32767 character limit in each cell (which I don't exactly know the definition of cell) of csv but I don't see how it can be relevant to number of rows in my case.

This is the code I read from serial port and save the value as the csv file (`ku` is a queue object in multiprocessing, `lock` is also used in multiprocessing to limit access to the file while it is being written, `delay_serial` is used to create a small delay between reading from serial port):

```
def make_measurement(delay_serial, lock, ku, filename_sensor):
    ser = serial.Serial(sPort, 115200)
    ser.close()
    ser.open()

    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        tmp_data = ser.readline()
        try:
            tmp_data = float(tmp_data.strip())
        except ValueError:
            tmp_data = np.nan

        this_data = [tmp_data, time.time()]
        sleep(delay_serial)
        with open(filename_sensor, 'a', newline='') as fp:
            # Pass the CSV  file object to the writer() function
            writer_object = writer(fp, dialect='excel')
            # Result - a writer object
            # Pass the data in the list as an argument into the writerow() function
            writer_object.writerow(this_data)
            # Close the file object
            fp.close()
        ku.put(this_data)
        lock.release()
```

UPDATE: Thanks to everyone for your help and comments. It seems the problem was with `ku.put(this_data)` that keeps the last reading in a buffer to be read as needed later in the code. Since I am saving all the data, instead of putting that last data in buffer, I read it from the saved CSV file. Doing so, now the CSV file can be saved (that seems to be) unlimitedly.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: it seems like you could/should avoid using the excel dialect if you don't want to be subject the limitations of excel csv files -- i.e., `writer(fp, dialect='excel')` seems to be at odds with your goals.

Comment: @topsail He's not exceeding the Excel limit. According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3 Excel allows up to 1 million rows, 16K columns, and 32K characters in a cell. His problems are happening after 32K rows with 2 columns, and the cells are tiny.

Comment: 1) `fp.close()` is redundant, the `with open() ...` is a context manager that will close the file on exit. 2) What is `ku.put(this_data)` doing? 3) Where is the file being saved on the Arduino or somewhere else?  And is there some size restriction on that location? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Additional questions: 1) What is value of `delay_serial`? 2) Could there be a connection timeout on the serial port?

Comment: @Barmar my mistake I was thinking perhaps this was the older `xls` file format row limit in effect (and I was put off by the OP speaking of rows and lines so much ... which I'm still not clear on ... are we trying to put all these lines in a single "cell"?). In any case, it turns out that the older excel row limit was 65,536 (I don't know how I could forget that). Still, I don't see a reason to use "excel csv" if that entails unnecessary restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code and it writes all the lines.

Edit your code based on it.

```
import csv

for i in range(100000):
    with open("test_file.csv",'a',newline='') as fl:
        writer = csv.writer(fl)
        writer.writerow([i,1.5*i])
        writer= None
        # No need to fl.close(), the with statement does that.
```

Also, there is not 32768 character limit for CSV file cells. That's an excel limitation. If you try to read a CSV file with excel you need to respect Excel cell, column, and row number limitation, that is

- 32,767 characters per cell
- 1,048,576 rows
- 16,384 columns.

You can see what specs re supported by Excel [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Note that these limitations are not inherent to CSV though.

Comment: I ran modified version with `range(10000) ` and `writer.writerow([i, (5 * i) * 't'])` to get a field with up to `49995` characters with no issues.

Comment: There is no limitation for CSV. however if you try to open a csv file that has cell lengths bigger than 32767 characters, it reads the CSV file falsely (tried it just now with excel and it had broken the cell to smaller ones randomly).

Comment: A CSV file does not have cells so I don't see how that is possible. Now if you are talking about importing a CSV file into Excel that is not what the OP is doing. Excel is not involved in their process other then `dialect='excel'`, which really has nothing to Excel. It is just a set of parameters to read/write a CSV file.

Comment: I did not say that CSV file has cells. You can write as much as you want on a CSV file and you can read it via any text reader or python. But, if you try to read the CSV file with excel (regardless of using "dialect='excel'"), then it will put each entry in a cell, if the length of that CSV entry is bigger than 32767 character, it will misinterpret/misread that entry.